# Have all Records in one Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how is possible to have all records of one field into one field

```
Id, No , FDevice
1 ,  1 ,  'A'
2 ,  1 ,  'B'
3 ,  1 ,  'C'
4 ,  2 ,  'D'
5 ,  2 ,  'E'
```

I want to have

```
 No , FDevice
 1  ,  A-B-C
 2  ,  D-E
```

Thank you  for your help

Answer (score 2):

use `STUFF()` - which inserts a string into another string.

```
SELECT
     [No],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '-' + [FDevice]
          FROM TableName
          WHERE [No] = a.[No]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS FDevice
FROM TableName AS a
GROUP BY [No]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2916/3)

Comment: +1 lovely answer! I was thinking of using a function that had a variable that concatenated with itself. But this is really elegant.

Comment: @PreetSangha just be sure you have no special characters in your data or you can end up with incorrect results, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There're a well-known solution for aggregate concatenation in SQL Server, using `select ... for xml path('')`, but I have to say that many people using it incorrectly. Correct way to do this would be

```
select
     a.[No],
     stuff(
         (
             select '-' + t.[FDevice]
             from TableName as t
             where t.[No] = a.[No]
             for xml path(''), type
         ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
     , 1, 1, '') as FDevice
from (select distinct [No] from TableName) as a;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00c00/2)</kbd>**

The main part is to use xml type inside the query and then to convert it into varchar using  `value` function, otherwise you can end up with incorrectly converted special chars like `'>', '<', '&'` and so on. SQLfiddle somehow doesn't show the difference, but here's a script which can show you what can happen if you don't use xml type:

```
declare @TableName table
    ([Id] int, [No] int, [FDevice] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO @TableName
    ([Id], [No], [FDevice])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A<'),
    (2, 1, 'B'),
    (3, 1, '&C'),
    (4, 2, 'D'),
    (5, 2, 'E')
;

SELECT
     [No],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '-' + [FDevice]
          FROM @TableName
          WHERE [No] = a.[No]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS FDevice
FROM @TableName AS a
GROUP BY [No];

outputs
No         FDevice
--------------------
1          A&lt;-B-&amp;C
2          D-E

select
     a.[No],
     stuff(
         (
             select '-' + t.[FDevice]
             from @TableName as t
             where t.[No] = a.[No]
             for xml path(''), type
         ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
     , 1, 1, '') as FDevice
from (select distinct [No] from @TableName) as a;

outputs
No         FDevice
--------------------
1          A<-B-&C
2          D-E
```